# Comparing 2 columns from separate dataframes and copy some row values from one df to another if column value matches in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

Im relatively new to pandas andpython . I have a simple problem but I can not find the solution . I have 2 dataframes DF1 and DF2 as shown in image

Both dataframes have ID coluumns. I wannt to check if the ID for a row in DF1 matches any of ID in DF2, then I want to copy the diameter value from DF2 and paste it to DF1 in a new column. Eventually what I want to achieve at the end is DF3 shown in image below.

Help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Dataframes DF1, DF2 and DF3]

Answer (score 1):

You may merge two dfs:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['id'], how='left')
```